# lexicographically minimum permutation of given zig zag permutation

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, permutation

here is a question I am working on.I tried alot but can't get better than O(n^2).

```
 You are given a set of numbers from 1 to K.And you need to find 
 the minimum possible lexicographical set of numbers with following
 constraints.You are given K numbers of sets of Yes 'Y' or NO 'N' from
 1 to K.And the swap is only possible if the value is 'Y'.Sorry for my
 poor English.Hope this example helps get you the problem. 
 NOTE: 1 < K < 101
 Take an example:
 K=3
Given set of numbers is :  3 1 2
                           N N Y
                           N N N
                           Y N N
     Here you can swap j and i+2 element since the value is Y.

Thus,the output would be   2 1 3
```

can someone suggest me a better approach than this probably in lower complexity?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear what does "minimum possible lexicographical set of numbers" mean? You want to make some valid swaps and get the minimum number (in other words, ordering with constrained swaps). Is it so?

Comment: yeah.you got the question right.

Answer (score 2):

Just consider the matrix given by the swappable elements. I think it is fair to assume that if arr[i][j] represents the element denoting if i can be swapped with j, then

```
arr[i][j] = arr[j][i] ; for all i, j pairs
```

Also, if *i* can be swapped with *j* and *j* can be swapped with *k*, then it is possible to swap *i* with *k* through *j*.

Using this information, we can see that if we can construct a set of indices such that for each element *i* in the set there exists at least one element *j* with which it can be swapped, then we can simply arrange the values at these indices in sorted order and that would be the lexicographically smallest arrangement possible for these indices. If we go on considering all such sets, then we would end up with the lexicographically smallest arrangement.

Another way to look at the problem (instead of viewing these as collection of disjoint sets), is to see this as a graph problem. If each index is a node and an edge between two indices if they can be swapped, then we need to find the different **Strongly Connected Components** (SCC) and sort the elements within each such component. This is obvious, if you note that any index in a strongly connected component cannot be swapped with a position outside this component and hence we can sort each SCC by itself and obtain desired result.

This question was also asked in [CodeSprint3](https://cs3.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4f846fced75d3) and my solution to the same is :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <queue>
#include <cstring>


using namespace std;

void sccSetInsertions (set<int>& indexSet, set<int>& valSet, const int& i, const int& val)
{
    indexSet.insert (i);
    valSet.insert(val);
}

void checkSCCMembers(const int& i, const int& k, int *arr, int *swaps, queue<int>& bfsQ,
                     set<int>& sccVals, set<int>& sccIndices, int *considered)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
    {
        if (swaps[j] == 1)
        {
            if (considered[j] == 0)
            {
                bfsQ.push(j);
                sccSetInsertions(sccIndices, sccVals, j, arr[j]);
                considered[j] = 1;
            }           
        }
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    int k, i, j;    
    cin >> k;   
    int arr[k];
    int swaps[k][k];

    for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    char c;    
    for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            cin >> c; 
            swaps[i][j] = (c == 'Y');
        }   
    }


    set<int> sccIndices, sccVals;
    queue<int> bfsQ;        
    int considered[k], tmp;

    bzero (considered, sizeof(int) * k);

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {   
        if (considered[i] == 1)
            continue;
        else
        {

            sccSetInsertions(sccIndices, sccVals, i, arr[i]);
            considered[i] = 1;            
        }
        checkSCCMembers (i, k, arr, swaps[i], bfsQ, sccVals, sccIndices, considered);
        while (bfsQ.size() > 0)
        {
            tmp = bfsQ.front();
            bfsQ.pop();            
            checkSCCMembers(tmp, k, arr, swaps[tmp], bfsQ, sccVals, sccIndices, considered);
        }

        set<int>::iterator itVal = sccVals.begin(), itIndex = sccIndices.begin();
        for(; itIndex != sccIndices.end(); itIndex++, itVal++)
        {
            arr[*itIndex] = *itVal;        
        }
        sccIndices.clear();
        sccVals.clear();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i];
        if (i != k - 1)
            cout << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any sorting algorithm. You just have to constrain your swaps. So you can use QuickSort, HeapSort etc for `O(nlgn)` complexity with swapping contraints.

Comment: I too thought of that..but I got into some problem.Newyz I will look into it once again. So implemented it with bubble sort :D

Comment: Quick sort would also give O(n^2) in worst case.

Comment: @Rndm I've mentioned HeapSort too. Merge sort can also be used.